# Angular Slider Component

Tags: angular, slider

I want to create a SliderComponent and implement it on different pages. Which slider should I use and how do I create a separate component for that?

I created a Slider Component with an slider example.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css']
})
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() youtubeURL!: string;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(): void { }
}
```

and an example Slider:

```
<div id="home-carousel" class="container p-0">
  <div id="carouselExampleDark" class="carousel carousel-dark slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="2000">
        <img [src]="https://angular.io/assets/images/logos/angular/angular.svg" height="500" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h2 class="text-white film-title">FILMTITEL</h2>
          <a href="">Zum Film</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

So how do I get it in my home.component.html?:

```
<div class="row slider align-items-center">
  <app-slider></app-slider>
</div>
```

this is the home.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

I get data from a service and inside this data is a Youtube link to every data entry.
So i need to iterate through this and display the Youtube link in the slider somehow.

Help plz.

Comment: I guess you want to look into ng-bootstrap. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/api#NgbCarousel

Answer (score 0):

Svensen, to use a component "SliderComponent" this component need been declared in one module (generally the .ts of a module we called as `mynameofmodule.module.ts`) in declarations)

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ ...],
  declarations: [ ...,SliderComponent ],
})
export class MyModuleModule { }
```

Futhermore, if you use your SliderComponent in another component, both need share the same module or your SliderComponent should be declared in a Module, exported and the module import in the Module where the component is declared. In code you has two options

```
//your slider.module.ts
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ ...],
  declarations: [ ...,SliderComponent ],
  exports:[SlideComponent] //<--see the "exports"
})
export class SliderModule { }

//another module where you declare a component that use SliderComponent
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ ...,SliderModule],
  declarations: [ ...,AnotherComponent ],
})
export class AnotherModule { }
```

Now in AnotherComponent you can use SliderComponent

The other option -only recomended in a little applications or if only you use SliderComponent in a few component that belong to the same Module

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ ...],
  declarations: [ ...,AnotherComponent,SliderComponent ],
})
export class MyModuleModule { }
```

As AnotherComponent and SliderComponent are in the same Module you can use it